# Creating ALOS PALSAR 1.0 level JAXA Orthorectified K & C Mosaic interferometry

Tags: gdal, envi, radar

JAXA is providing free access to PALSAR 50m Orthorectified K & C Mosaic.

The files are not in the typical PALSAR format. I'm looking for apps that can read and export this data.

Is it possible to create interferometry using these products?

They formatted that product differently than raw imagery, with a _HDR file and an _IMG file for each band.
http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/kc_mosaic/kc_map_50.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global 50 m mosaics available to download from http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/palsar_fnf/fnf_index.htm are mapped binary files with an ENVI header. You should just be able to read them using GDAL with the ENVI driver (I've not had any problems doing this).

You need to apply the following equation to calibrate HH and HV data to gamma0

```
gamma0 = 10*log10(DN^2) - 83.0
```

It is not possible to use these mosaic data for interferometry as the phase information is lost during the processing (you need the Level 1.1 single look complex data data for interferometry). The processing is described in:

> M. Shimada and T. Otaki, "Generating Continent-scale High-quality SAR
>   Mosaic Datasets: Application to PALSAR Data for Global Monitoring,"
>   IEEE JSTARS Special Issue on Kyoto and Carbon Initiative, vol. 3,
>   Issue 4, 2010, pp.637-656.